# Cloudbees PHP date timezone

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, timezone, cloudbees

I'm trying to build a PHP Symfony application on [Cloudbees](https://www.cloudbees.com/) and when the composer try to warm up cache, it's getting the following warning and failing the build:

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

I'm using the following code, recommended by the cloudbees documentation, to use php 5.5 and set the php.ini file.

```
wget -q https://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/distributions/ci-addons/php/use-php
PHP_VERSION=5.5.16 . ./use-php
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mkdir -p /tmp/php
echo "date.timezone = 'America/New_York'" > /tmp/php/php.ini
export PHPRC=/tmp/php
```

I've did a "php -i" on the build stack and received this response:

```
PHP Version => 5.5.16

System => Linux jenkins 3.9.4-1-mansion #2 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 19 16:54:20 UTC 2013 x86_64
Build Date => Sep 15 2014 01:12:27
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/scratch/jenkins/php/php-5.5.16-x86_64' '--with-curl' '--with-openssl'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /scratch/jenkins/php/php-5.5.16-x86_64/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /tmp/php/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)

(...)

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2014.5
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => America/New_York

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => America/New_York => America/New_York
```

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: php-cli and php for the webserver often don't use the same php.ini, can you confirm with other settings that it's the right php.ini?

Comment: @GerdK, i saw this question before and it doesn't solved.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard, it's a build in the CI environment, it's supposed to use the php.ini in the PHPRC env var. I edited the question with more information of the phpinfo().

Comment: Sorry, I've been probably too lazy with this flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple build steps, the PHPRC environment variable is not going to persist across steps. You need to set the variable and run your PHP commands all in the same shell script / build step, or else use the Environment Injector plugin to set PHPRC in a way that will persist throughout all steps.